# get a field of wordpress custom taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have registered a new taxonomy and assigned a custom field (image) to its term (subcategory) using Advanced Custom Fields 4.4.0. Somehow I can't get it displayed on custom page template.

```
$term = get_query_var('term');
$term = get_term_by('slug', $term, 'gallery');
$termid = $term->term_id;
get_field('featured_image', $termid);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used the_field() ?

Comment: you get the field content by calling the_field('field_name');

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing 'get_field()' or store it in a variable then echo it.

```
$custom = get_field('featured_image', $termid);
echo $custom;
```

Comment: Yes, have tried that and also the_field(). I'm not using it within the loop of posts, I assume it's not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right. But you must echo or print to write to screen. Or you can using `the_field();` function.

Comment: Yes, have tried that and also the_field(). I'm not using it within the loop of posts, I assume it's not mandatory.

Comment: get_field('slug',$term->id) can use outside of loop.